# struggling with document root for multiple projects

Tags: php, apache, dns, server, subdomain

I am having a challenge currently since I need to structure multiple projects and multiple subdomains. I want to have this structure:

```
--> core
-----> core-phpclasses
-----> core-js
-----> core-css 
-----> ....
--> project1 (customer.domain.tld)
-----> css
-----> php
-----> js 
-----> ...
---> project2 (customer.seconddomain.tld)
-----> css
-----> php
-----> js 
-----> ...
```

So as you can see, my projects are "independent", while they still need access to the core files, to work. core files are those, which are for all projects the same. the files within the projects are independent.

Since those projects are "isolated" through being a subdomain, they can't access the files outside of document root (only with php includes but doesn't work with css + js etc.)

Moreover those files will be hosted on several (customer) servers. So with every new customer, the domain will change.

Short version: It's basically a software-package including 2 sub-packages of  which will be hosted on a unique system per customer. The sub-packages need the core files, since they have the same functionality for all projects.
Every customer has a subdomain.

How could I handle the problem to make the core files access-able for all the projects, although they can't access them outside their document root?

Comment: For the server side files(e.g. `.php`) it's not a problem as you've noticed - client side (`.css`, `.js` etc) you need to reference an absolute URL - you could have something like *static.domain.tld* as a sort of CDN for shared resources : e.g. `<img src="//static.domain.tld/img/mycat.jpg" ... />` - there might be a Cross Domain issue with JS though.

Comment: yes I was thinking about that too, but since every customer will have an own server, it won't really work. Because then I would either host the core files on also a unique system or change it for every customer. like:

unique-server:
<img src='core.domain.tld' .../>
or....... for every customer: 
<img src='core.customer.domain.tld'/>

Comment: Why can't you simply map those core resources into the virtual servers using an `Alias` directive?

Comment: not sure how exactly you mean it @arkascha. Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Well, use references like `/core/css/foo.css` for example. In combination with something like `Alias /core/ /path/to/core/` you have what you want. This obviously requires the folders to be present in the local file system. So it works for _virtual_ hosts. If you really use separate _systems_ for the http hosts, then you'd either have to copy or mount that file system portion.

Comment: wow thank you very much!!! I think that will do the trick. I hope at least. I have to rethink all it through but this is probably the solution. I didn't know about Alias :) Thank you very much again! Have a great day.